# PHP MySQL Add On to longtext

Tags: php, mysql

Well I have a code that updates the LongText in the MySQL. Here's the code:

```
$id = rand(1, 100);
$puffleString = "{$id}|{$name}|{$type}|100|100|100,";
$coins = $this->delCoins(800);
$this->write("%xt%pn%-1%" . $coins . "%" . $puffleString . "%");
$puffles = $this->c("puffles");
$puff = $puffles."%".$puffleString;
$type2 = 750 + $type;
setData("UPDATE accs SET puffles='{$puff}' WHERE id='" . $this->ID . "';");
```

As you can see the puffleString has a comma at the end, so everytime I use this function that long text disappears and sets up a new one. I want it so it add ons to the long text
Any idea? Should I use implode?

Comment: `puffles=CONCAT(puffles, '{$puff}')`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to append `{$puff}` like such:

```
setData("UPDATE accs SET puffles=CONCAT(puffles,'{$puff}') WHERE id='{$this->ID}';");
```

Please note that you should be using a prepared statement (unless you can absolutely guarantee that `$name` and `$type` don't come from the user)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the concat function in mysql. For example.

```
UPDATE accs set puffles = CONCAT(puffles, '{$puff}') WHERE id = $id
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Make sure you watch for SQL injection.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection